# How to get what is searched in CoreSpotlight?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, spotlight, corespotlight

The iOS9 Search API provides apps to store indexes and search them through the spotlight. Is there a way getting the searched text which is entered in spotlight? More specifically is there a way to search dynamic texts which can't be indexed. This searched text will be queried to an API and a view will be generated according to the searched text just like `Search Web/Appstore/Maps`.

[image]

[image]